# Requests repeating issue python

Tags: python, python-requests

So I’m using requests python library to make a series of requests ie

Req1 then Req2 then Req 3

Issue is the req1 keeps repeating itself and is not going forward to req2

Any help please

Code

While true:
  Try:

```
      session = requests.session()

     r = session.get('Url').text    #req1

     postdata = 'the post data'

     myheader = {'the headers'}

     n = session.post('Myurl ', data=postdata, headers=myheaders).text       #req2
```

Request keeps repeating the get request

Comment: Please post your code so contributors can review it

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: @ibaguio added code

Comment: can you be so kind to also comment your code on which is req1, req2, req3. also i've noticed, your headers is a python set, not a dict

Comment: @ibaguio done it follows order

Comment: so what do you mean here by req1 repeating itself?

Comment: @ibaguio I tried Dict too same issue in the console if I print the response on req 1 it keeps doing the same request and printing the response instead of moving to second request

Comment: there must be something incorrect with how you execute the code. are you running it in the terminal? or executing a file

Comment: Terminal the code is enclosed in a while loop look at edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation could be the problem as only the indented code from the while True loop will be repeated.
This in return would cause the rest of the code to not run as the loop will never end.

Some errors I also noticed were:

- After the `try:` there is no `except:`
- The T in `Try:` is also uppercased when it should be lowercased
- The T in `True:` should be uppercase as well
- The w in `While` should be lowercased

An proper example would be

```
while True: 
  try:
     session = requests.session()

     r = session.get('https://example.com').text    #req1

     postdata = {'data': 'data'}

     myheader = {'header': 'header'}

     n = session.post('https://example.com', data=postdata, headers=myheaders).text   #req2
  except:
    # Some logic for after a error occurs
    # ex:
    print("Error has occured")
```

Now this is just nit picking and isn't all that relevant but the point of using `requests.session()` is to be a faster version of typing out `requests` so setting it to `session` is a little redundant.